# Flurry Analytics: How to Configure Email Id in Flurry admin?

Tags: android, analytics, flurry

I have 10 android applications created in a single Flurry account. My requirement is that, I want to configure one of my client's email id as viewer in one application. So that the customer can get the statistics delivered to his mail id.

Can I configure an email id in Flurry Analytics admin page. Is it possible?
If, posiible, then anybody explain how?

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on **manage** text (top of Flurry home page). It will redirect you to Manage Company page.
2. In Manage Company  page, click on **invite users** text (top right corner of **Comapny Users** table)
3. Add email address of the desired user
4. Select **Product Roles** as Viewer
5. If you want to limit this user's access to single application among 10 apps, then tick the **Limit Application Access** check box. Choose application name listed down.
6. Tap **Send** button

That's it. You have succesfully invited your client :)